# How to make a random list of a specific length without duplicates in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `randomnames/1` that generates a random list of three different names. The names are in a database and I already have a predicate for one random name:

```
name(1, Mary).
name(2, Pat).
name(3, James).
name(4, Bob).
name(5, Susan).

random_name(Name):- 
  random(0, 6, N),    
  name(N, Name).
```

To get this in a list, someone suggested I should do:

```
random_names([A,B,C]) :-
    random_name(A),
    random_name(B),
    random_name(C).
```

The only problem with this is that it's possible to get duplicates in the list generated. I can't figure out how to fix that issue. I could write a new predicate for removing duplicates, but how would I substitute the duplicate with another variable then, so that the list still has three elements? And how would I even write the remove predicate when there isn't a clear head and tail in the `random_names` predicate?

Answer (score 3):

When programming in Prolog, think in terms of **conditions** that your solutions must satisfy.

Currently, you have already figured out how to describe a list with three elements, where each element is a random name.

That's a good start, but not yet sufficient: **In addition**, you now want to describe the condition that the elements are pairwise distinct.

So, think about how to *describe* a list of three elements where all elements are pairwise distinct.

I give you a start, using `dif/2` to express *disequality* of terms in a sound way (see [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)):

```
three_distinct_elements([A,B,C]) :-
        dif(A, B),
        dif(A, C),
        dif(B, C).
```

You may find a more general and more elegant way to describe this for lists with more than 3 elements. However, the above suffices to solve the task at hand.

So, it only remains to *combine* the predicates you already have, using for example:

```
three_distinct_random_names(Ls) :-
        random_names(Ls),
        three_distinct_elements(Ls).
```

This is simply the **conjunction** of conditions which you have already implemented. In total, solutions of this predicate will give you what you want: A list with three distinct random names.

However, the predicate may also *fail* (Exercise: *Why?*).

To try the predicate *until it finds a solution*, use for example `repeat/0`:

```
?- repeat, three_distinct_random_names(Ls).
```

There are also better ways to solve this. However, as a first approximation, I recommend to focus on good *building-blocks*, describing the conditions you want to satisfy.

I have a general comment on what you write:

> I could write a new predicate for **removing** duplicates, but how would I **substitute** the duplicate with another variable then, so that the list still has three elements?

This is all worded very *imperatively*: You think here about "removing", "substituting" etc. To get the most out of Prolog, focus on **describing** the conditions that **must hold** for the solutions you want to find!

You want to find a list without duplicates? *Describe* what such a a list must look like. You want random names? *Describe* what such a name looks like, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer! As for why the predicate can fail, my guess would be that if there is in fact a duplicate found, one of the `dif` will fail, then `three_distinct_elements` fails and then the whole predicate fails. Is that right?

Comment: Do you think it's possible with your code to just get one answer that doesn't fail? I need this predicate as part for another one, so I can't do `repeat` in the query. Adding `repeat` in the code will give me a lot of backtracking results and adding a `cut` seems to negate the `repeat`. Is it possible to do both repeat and cut?

Comment: Avoid `!/0`, use `once((repeat,...))`!

Comment: I've been trying to do once((repeat, )) for a while now, but no matter what I try I still can't get the code to not fail. Any tips?

Comment: I mean use `once((repeat,three_distinct_random_names(Ls)))`. This repeats until there is a solution, and then **commits** to that first solution. It is better to use `once/1` because its effect is more local.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, but it keeps giving me the out of local stack error. 
`three_distinct_random_names(Ls) :-
        once((repeat,three_distinct_random_names(Ls))),
        three_distinct_elements(Ls),
        random_names(Ls).`

Comment: I mean to post this goal on the toplevel. You don't need to modify the definition I posted in any way! If you want, you can add an additional definition that simply wraps the goal into the `once((repeat,...))`. This keeps all concerns separate: `three_distinct_random_names/1` is true if it finds a solution. The additional `once((repeat,...))` wrapper simply ensures that we try as often as necessary to find a solution. As I think you already see from these complications, random numbers hinging on implicit global states do not mesh particularly well with pure relations, to put it mildly.

Comment: Yes this exercise thing has been horrible haha. I understand it now though, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using Swi-Prolog you can use very handy randseq/3 predicate which comes bundled with Swi. randseq/3 generates list of all distinct random numbers in range from 1 to N. After getting this list generated all that remains is mapping numbers to names:

```
name(1, 'Mary').
name(2, 'Pat').
name(3, 'James').
name(4, 'Bob').
name(5, 'Susan').

random_names(Names, Count) :-
    % 5 is the amount of names available in database
    randseq(Count, 5, L),
    maplist(name, L, Names).
```

Usage examples:

```
?- random_names(Names, 3).
Names = ['Mary', 'James', 'Susan'].

?- random_names(Names, 5).
Names = ['Susan', 'Bob', 'James', 'Mary', 'Pat'].
```