# Get A Random Subset of Solutions

Tags: functional-programming, prolog, swi-prolog

I couldn't find any related question on StackOverflow, and I'm not sure that this is feasible in Prolog, but here's my problem:

Given a set of constraints where I can expect an enormous number of solutions from Prolog that may take hours to come up, can I opt not to wait for the full set of solutions, but instead get the "first" but randomized solutions?

For an extremely small example,

```
between(0, 100, X), between(0, 100, Y), X+Y>100.
```

will promptly give me a predictable set of `X=1, Y=100; X=2, Y=100, X=3, Y=100` etc. Suppose the example instead takes hours to compute, is there a way to get - say 35 (a user parameter) - solutions that are randomly ordered, like `X=79, Y=43; X=4, Y=98`, etc?

It's been a while since I last did Prolog, so I'm back to being a beginner!

Comment: Random as in the sense of "unique" solutions, or is repition possible?

Comment: One of the main reasons why Prolog is not easy to *randomize*, is because the order of computation really matters sometimes. Especially for programs with a cut (`!`), where picking a random clause thus could do thing that are otherwise impossible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Re: unique vs repetition. I'd say unique.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I had 2 ideas but I'm not sure they make any sense: 1. Write 35 random statements as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46704922) and parameterize the writing of any number of random statements somehow 2. Use `randseq` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711094).

Comment: I did find [a strategy for randomizing solution order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427112), but I'm not sure how to limit the number of solutions (parameterized), at least in a way that avoids computing all solutions.

Comment: See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852980/prolog-findall-for-limited-number-of-solutions) for ECLipSe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [call_nth](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_nth/2)/2, coupled with [random_between](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=random_between/3)/3:

```
?- random_between(1,8,X),call_nth(member(E,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),X).
X = E, E = 1.

?- random_between(1,8,X),call_nth(member(E,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),X).
X = E, E = 6.
```

Comment: Does `call_nth` force Prolog to find all solutions first (genuine question)? One of my goals is to avoid doing that because it takes a few hours to find all solutions.

Comment: no, actually only the required ones to reach the counter.